# Watch for file changes and run headlessly

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

When I run `cypress open`, the Cypress Test Runner will open + browser and tests are rerun on every file change.

Is it possible to rerun test automatically but in headless mode?

Comment: I don't think file watching capabilities gets applied on headless mode of Cypress run. I just gave a try with `npx cypress run --no-exit`; but, didn't work on file change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Extracted directly from [the Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests.html#Configuration)

> Nothing is watched during cypress run.
>   The watchForFileChanges property is only in effect when running Cypress using cypress open.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a built-in feature but you might want to take a look at https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-watch-and-reload

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.